# How to avoid widows and orphans in \sections?

Tags: sectioning, widows-orphans

In the following example, the section `11.1` should be placed on the page 6 for better readability. This could be done manually by adding `\clearpage` before the `\subsection`.

I tried from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/643589/85416) the following:

```
\usepackage[avoid-all]{widows-and-orphans}
```

However it doesn't quite work as expected:

[image]

How can I tell LaTeX to automatically add a page break if "most" of the section content is on the next page?

Comment: "Most" of the section isn't exactly something TeX has a direct access to. But from your screenshot the problem seems to be a large table, and widows/orphans penalties can't really help out much here.

Comment: @campa I agree, but is there any workaround? For instance placing what "should" remains on the same page in a block `\begin{keep-on-same-page}[always]`

Comment: Half a dozen possibilities come to my mind. Which one might be suited to your case depends on the code you don't show.

Comment: you have shown no code so it's not easy to help, you have not even shown what is after supra? since that line is short that is presumably(?) the end of the paragraph so widows and orphan control can not have any effect since they affect page breaking within a paragraph. If you are on a final copy-edit/proof read and just want to force things, stick `\clearpage` before the section.